# QueryString is empty during ASP.NET Core 8 MVC form post

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, query-string, asp.net-core-8

*Note: the answer may be in either VB.NET or C#. I have no preference for this Q&A.*

I'm following [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-8.0) to build a simple ASP.NET Core 8 MVC application that uses cookie authentication. I'm running into a problem where the query string on the URL isn't being sent to the controller. The value for `Request.QueryString` is an empty string.

Here's my URL:

```
https://localhost:55387/Account/SignIn?ReturnUrl=%2FContacts
```

Here's my controller:

```
Public Class AccountController
  <HttpPost>
  Public Async Function SignInAsync(Setting As Setting) As Task(Of IActionResult)
    Dim ReturnUrl As String = Me.Request.Query("ReturnUrl")

    ' etc.
  End Function
End Class
```

...and here's my view:

```
@model Db.Models.Setting

@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Sign In";
}

<h1>Sign In</h1>
<h4>Enter the site PIN</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="SignIn">
      <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

      <div class="form-group col-5">
        <label asp-for="AuthPin" class="control-label"></label>
        <input id="authPin" asp-for="AuthPin" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="AuthPin" class="text-danger"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input id="signInButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Sign In" disabled />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The trouble is that the example is for a Razor Pages application. Mine is MVC. In the example, this works just fine:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
  this.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
}
```

Here, the `returnURL` variable is populated as expected. But in MVC, we don't have an `OnPostAsync` function. I'm handling everything in the controller action. And the action isn't picking up the query string for some reason.

There's [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37114867), but in my case there is no `Url` property on the `Request` instance. There is a `Path` property, but its value doesn't contain a query string (*"/Account/SignIn"*).

There's also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14307386), but adding a `ReturnUrl` parameter on the `SignIn` post action didn't help.

How can I get my controller/action to collect the query string on form `POST`?

Comment: Have you looked at the actual HTTP protocol traffic in your browser's devtools?

Comment: I did just now, and the query string is present.

Comment: Why are you using query string params with a POST? Use a view model.

Comment: @Alex — I'm not, specifically. The MVC framework is. That's the query string that's automatically appended when an unauthenticated user attempts to access a controller that's decorated with `AuthorizeAttribute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around the problem using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40293642). It's not the prettiest solution, but it works at least.

In the view:

```
@Html.Hidden("QueryString", @Context.Request.QueryString)
```

...and then in the controller:

```vb
<HttpPost>
Public Async Function SignInAsync(QueryString As String) As Task(Of IActionResult)
  Dim oQueryString As NameValueCollection
  Dim oDictionary As RouteValueDictionary
  Dim sReturnUrl As String
  Dim oResult As IActionResult

  oQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(QueryString)
  oDictionary = New RouteValueDictionary
  sReturnUrl = oQueryString("ReturnUrl")

  Array.ForEach(oQueryString.AllKeys, Sub(Key) oDictionary.Add(Key, oQueryString(Key)))

  oResult = Me.RedirectToAction("SignIn", oDictionary)

  ' etc.
End Function
```

That did the trick.